# Plotly not showing correct colors when using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, 3d, plotly

For my dataset, I wanted to change the colors of the "Labels" data that is shown in the 3d scatter plot, but I have been unsuccessful.

I keep getting these default colors:

[image]

This is the code that I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import seaborn as sns

# Data
data = pd.read_csv('SamplePlotlyData.csv')
labels = data['Label'].values
data = data.drop(columns=['Label']).values

fig = px.scatter_3d(data,
            x= data[:,0], y= data[:,1], z = data[:,2], 
            labels={'x':'PCA-1', 'y':'PCA-2','z':'PCA-3'},
            color=labels,
            color_discrete_sequence=["blue", "goldenrod", "magenta"],
            title='3d Plot of Top 3 PCA components')
fig.show()
```

Can you assist me in correctly changing the color palette of the 3d scatter plot?

I am using jupyter notebook 6.0.3 with seaborn version 0.11.2

Here is my dataset:

```
36  37  38  39  Label
0.22717583  -0.1028256  -0.041157354    0.047657568 0
-1.242205   2.611936    1.5563084   -0.64137465 0
0.39261582  0.40208274  0.2835228   0.26541463  0
-4.296567   -1.3980201  -0.67690927 -0.941123   0
-1.5278594  1.103121    -1.4688232  -1.139884   0
2.35497 -1.3783572  0.4808609   -1.4851115  1
-0.055658106    -0.19007513 -0.40134305 -0.34722504 1
0.051404    -0.6016376  0.26404122  -0.42829922 1
-0.47935575 -0.049984064    0.67335206  0.123305336 1
0.57357675  0.9523434   -0.05714764 -0.6305638  1
0.1044371   1.2541072   0.1957058   0.083972946 2
0.47575372  0.18598396  0.069036044 0.63252586  2
-0.7613742  0.81920165  0.43508404  0.280004    2
-0.16776349 0.9296196   -1.1710609  0.86310846  2
-0.20844702 0.3536006   0.01729327  -0.28363776 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons you are seeing the colors is because your `Label` column is integer. Seaborn thinks it is numerical and uses continuous colors. So, you will need to change that to categorical using `.astype(str)`. Also, I think you are moving `Label` to a `labels` and deleting the column, which is not required. So, I have updated it as below. Also attached the output plot.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import seaborn as sns

# Data
data = pd.read_csv('SamplePlotlyData.csv')

data['Label'] = data['Label'].astype(str) #Make it string
#data = data.drop(columns=['Label']).values

fig = px.scatter_3d(data,
            x= 36, y= 37, z = 38, #Updated here - just use column names
            labels={'x':'PCA-1', 'y':'PCA-2','z':'PCA-3'},
            color='Label', #Column name of Label
            color_discrete_sequence=["blue", "goldenrod", "magenta"],
            title='3d Plot of Top 3 PCA components')
fig.show()
```

**Output**

[image]